# mpiexec.hydra - how to run MPI process on machines where locations of hydra_pmi_proxy are different?

Tags: mpi, mpich

I am trying to run a simple MPI program using MPICH over a cluster of two machines. However, one is running Fedora 17 and the other is running Debian Squeeze - not necessarily a problem, but the issue is that the two distros put their mpi execs in different directories:

When I run the following from host1:

```
mpiexec -hosts host2 -np 1 -wdir /home/chris/src/mpi/ ./mpitest
```

it fails with the following error

```
bash: /usr/lib/mpich2/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be because `hydra_pmi_proxy` is installed in `/usr/lib/mpich2/bin` on the Fedora machine but in `/usr/bin` on the Debian machine. I assume that when I spawn the process from host1 via ssh, it expects to find hydra_pmi_proxy in the same place on host2.

The program runs ok on both machines if I just run it locally on that node - I only get a problem when trying to run it on both.

I have searched the MPICH documentation for a way to override to remote path to `hydra_pmi_proxy`, but to no avail.

Can I do this somehow? I thought one of the advantages of MPICH was that it can easily handle hetrogeneous hosts....

Any insights would be most appreciated!

Comment: What about just adding a symlink to `hydra_pmi_proxy` under `/usr/lib/mpich2/bin` on Debian as a quick hack?

Comment: That sort of worked (I am getting errors pertaining to communication issues now), but seems a bit dirty!

Comment: Looking at the Hydra source, it seems that the frontend is responsible for figuring out the path to `hydra_pmi_proxy` (in `HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters`), and this path is then reused across all nodes.  But I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of Hydra, so I could be wrong.  I guess try [submitting a ticket](https://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/mpich2/).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem not installing mpich hydra and the terminal (eg apt-get install MPICH2 or hydra). But instead I downloaded the source code: http://www.mpich.org/downloads/ (being the stable version).
  Then I ran the following command on the machines Master and slave: export PATH = / home / you / mpich: $ PATH (On my computer I installed on my mpich directory).

Just solved this problem!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by installing MPICH via its source code and mount the installation directory in the node in the same directory as the directory on server. then use export PATH = /home/you/mpich-installation-directory/bin: $PATH only on server.

Answer (score 0):

This problem  can be solved in NFS configuration with: `exportfs -var` (in master machine).

You have your `/mirror` directory, but it is necessary to add the directory `/usr` in `/etc/exports`:

```
/usr *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

In the client machine, edit `/etc/fstab` and add:

```
master-ip/usr   /usr nfs defaults 0 0
```

Save and run the command `mount -a`.

After run `df -h` to see the mounted directory from master in slave/client.