# bash: /usr/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, mpi, cluster-computing, mpich

I am struggling to set up an MPI cluster, following the [Setting Up an MPICH2 Cluster in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) tutorial. I have something running and my machine file is this:

```
pythagoras:2  # this will spawn 2 processes on pythagoras
geomcomp      # this will spawn 1 process on geomcomp
```

The tutorial states:

> and run it (the parameter next to -n specifies the number of processes to spawn and distribute among nodes):
>   mpiu@ub0:~$ mpiexec -n 8 -f machinefile ./mpi_hello

With -n 1 and -n 2 it runs fine, but with -n 3, it fails, as you can see below:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:/mirror$ mpiexec -n 1 -f machinefile ./mpi_hello            
Hello from processor 0 of 1
gsamaras@pythagoras:/mirror$ mpiexec -n 2 -f machinefile ./mpi_hello
Hello from processor 0 of 2
Hello from processor 1 of 2
gsamaras@pythagoras:/mirror$ mpiexec -n 3 -f machinefile ./mpi_hello
bash: /usr/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: No such file or directory
{hungs up}
```

Maybe that parameter next to -n specifies the number of machines? I mean the number of processes is stated in the machinefile, isn't it? Also, I have used 2 machines for the MPI cluster (hope this is the case and the output I am getting is not only from the master node (i.e. pythagoras), but also from the slave one (i.e. geomcomp)).

*Edit_1*

Well I think that the parameter next to -n actually specifies the number of processes, since in the tutorial I linked to, it uses 4 machines and the machine file implies that 8 processes will run. Then why we need that parameter next to -n though? Whatever the reason is, I still can't get why my run fails with -n 3.

*Edit_2*

Following Edit_1, it -n 3 is logical, since my machinefile implies 3 processes to be spawned.

*Edit_3*

I think that the problem lies when it tries to spawn a process in the slave node (i.e. geomcomp).

*Edit_4*

pythagoras runs on Debian 8, while geomcomp runs on Debian 6. The machines are of same architecture. The problem lies in geomcomp, since I tried `mpiexec -n 1 ./mpi_hello` there and said that no daemon runs.

So, I got, in *pythagoras*:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ mpichversion
MPICH Version:      3.1
MPICH Release date: Thu Feb 20 11:41:13 CST 2014
MPICH Device:       ch3:nemesis
MPICH configure:    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-shared --prefix=/usr --enable-fc --disable-rpath --disable-wrapper-rpath --sysconfdir=/etc/mpich --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --includedir=/usr/include/mpich --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich --with-hwloc-prefix=system --enable-checkpointing --with-hydra-ckpointlib=blcr
MPICH CC:   gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O2
MPICH CXX:  g++ -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
MPICH F77:  gfortran -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -O2
MPICH FC:   gfortran -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ which mpiexec
/usr/bin/mpiexec
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ which mpirun
/usr/bin/mpirun
```

where in *geomcomp* I got:

```
gsamaras@geomcomp:~$ mpichversion
-bash: mpichversion: command not found
gsamaras@geomcomp:~$ which mpiexec
/usr/bin/mpiexec
gsamaras@geomcomp:~$ which mpirun
/usr/bin/mpirun
```

I had installed MPICH2, like the tutorial instructed. What should I do? I am working on `/mirror` at the master node. It is mounted on the slave node.

<sub>1. This relevant question,
    [mpiexec.hydra - how to run MPI process on machines where locations of hydra_pmi_proxy are different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387356/mpiexec-hydra-how-to-run-mpi-process-on-machines-where-locations-of-hydra-pmi),
    is different from mine, but it might be the case here too.
 2. Damn it, the only Hydra I know is a Greek island, what am I missing?
    :/</sub>

Comment: It is possible (likely, I think) that when you use the `-n` option with a number less than 3, `mpiexec` is using the first processors available from the machinefile and ignores the rest. As such, for `-n 1` and `-n 2`, you are using only the machine pythagoras. When you try to run `-n 3`, it tries to use geomcomp as well. Is geomcomp set up to use MPI? Remote into that machine and try `mpiexec -n 1 ./mpi_hello` (without the `-machinefile` option). If that causes an error, there's your problem.

Comment: @R_Kapp thanks for the answer. Yes this what I thought too now, that geomcomp does not run anything (I checked with getting the IP address from the C code). When I try to do what you say, it says that I have no daemon running, so (after I read this http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/MPICH#Test_MPD), I got this: `gsamaras@geomcomp:/mirror$   mpd &
[1] 12036
gsamaras@geomcomp:/mirror$ configuration file /home/gsamaras/.mpd.conf not found
A file named .mpd.conf file must be present in the user's home...`

Comment: MPD has been depreciated for at least  several releases.   Stick with hydra.

Comment: OK @RobLatham, I just said it because it was the message I got in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you've identified a genuine shortcomming of Hydra: there should be some way to tell it the paths on the other nodes are different.

Where is mpich installed on pythagoras?  Where is mpich installed on geocomp?

In the simplest configuration, you would have, for example, a common home directory, and you would have installed mpich into ${HOME}/soft/mpich.

Hydra might not be starting a "login shell" on the remote machine.  If you add the MPICH installation path to your PATH environment variable, you'll have to do so in a file like .bashrc (or whatever the equivalent for your shell is).

To test this, try 'ssh geocomp mpichversion' and 'ssh pythagoras mpichversion' and plain old 'mpichversion'.  That should tell you something about how your environment is set up.

In your case, your environment is really strage!  debian 8 and debian 6 and it looks like not even the same versions of MPICH..   I think, thanks to the ABI initiative, that MPICH-3.1 and newer will work with MPICH-3.1, but if you have a version of MPICH that pre-dates the "MPICH2 to MPICH" conversion, there are no such gaurantees.

And setting ABI aside, you've got an MPICH that expects the hydra launcher (the debian 8 version) and an MPICH that expects the MPD launcher. (the debian 6 version)

And even if you do have recent enough packages, the only way things can work is if you have the same architecture on all machines.   ABI, as Ken points out, does not mean suppore for heterogeneous environments.

remove the distro packages and build MPICH yourself on both machines.

Comment: Check me edit, which should help you provide an answer!

Comment: actually, the followup question lives here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666741/build-mpich2-from-source/30763655

Comment: The ABI compatibility initiative does not allow mixing and matching of MPICH versions across processes. You must ensure you are using the same MPICH version on all your machines.

Comment: Definitely.  I'll edit to be more clear.  There is so much else odd in this environment.