# how to solve error in running MPI in amazon EC2?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, mpi

I have written a code using mpi4py and I want to run it on an ec2 instance. when I use this command:

```html
mpiexec -n 2 python -m mpi4py ./MyCode/test4.py
```

I face this error:

```html
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-18-30] HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file hydra_pmi_proxy (No such file or directory)
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-18-30] HYD_pmcd_pmiserv_proxy_init_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:448): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-18-30] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-18-30] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:196): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-18-30] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:336): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: /usr/bin/hydra\_pmi\_proxy: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605380/bash-usr-bin-hydra-pmi-proxy-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: try using the absolute path to your python interpreter (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`), assuming of course it is installed on all your nodes and at the same location.